# Найти количество слов палиндромов/перевертышей в строке

Tags: c++, строки

Для начала попытался сделать так, чтобы программа искала слова и записывала их в массив, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было проверить массив как отдельное слово. Не могу найти ошибку.

```
void flipFlop(string &str) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0') {
            string word;
            while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0') {
                word[j] = str[i];
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            cout << word << endl;
            i = 0;
            j = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так а в чем ошибка? Дополните вопрос

Comment: В последний раз выводило ошибку о том что я вышел за границы массива, сейчас вообще не запускается. Думаю что ошибка связана с динамическим массивом

Comment: Да, и еще когда я очищаю динамическую память после того как массив отработал (delete[] word), тоже выдает ошибку.

Comment: а можете объяснить почему вы не используете std::string для word?

Comment: потому что размер строки должен постоянно меняться, тк слова разного размера, и я не смогу обратиться к j-му элементу не задав строке начальное значение

Comment: я попытался переписать код с помощью строки word, но у меня не получилось

Comment: прикрепил код к посту

Comment: конечно у вас ничего не получилось - вы обращаетесь к пустой строке

Answer (score 1):

Сперва хочу заметить, что не стоит в `c++` использовать "голые" указатели на вручную алоцированую память. Дело в том, что создается опасность, что вы не освободите память из-за того, что забудите или досрочно выйдите из цикла и т.д. Тем более когда это касается строк - для них есть замечательный контейнер: `std::string` который вы тоже используете, но, почему-то только отчасти.

Вот пример как можно реализовать поиск полиндромов средствами `c++`:3 вида контейнеров (`std::string`, `std::list`, `std::set`) и всего один алгоритм (`std::copy`)

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <regex>
#include <set>

using StringList = std::list<std::string>;
using Polyndroms = std::set<std::string>;

StringList getWordList(const std::string &str) {
  StringList retval;

  std::regex reg{R"(\w+)"};

  std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator{str.begin(), str.end(), reg},
            std::sregex_token_iterator{},
            std::back_inserter(retval));

  return retval;
}

Polyndroms getPolyndroms(const StringList &list) {
  Polyndroms retval;

  for (const std::string &word : list) {
    std::string revertWord;
    std::copy(word.rbegin(), word.rend(), std::back_inserter(revertWord));

    if (word == revertWord) { // then the word is polyndrom
      retval.insert(word);
    }
  }

  return retval;
}

int main() {
  std::string str;
  std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{std::cin},
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{},
            std::back_inserter(str));

  StringList words = getWordList(str);

  Polyndroms polyndroms = getPolyndroms(words);

  std::copy(polyndroms.begin(),
            polyndroms.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Программа выведет все полиндромы из ввода в алфавитном порядке и без повторов. Можно отметить больший расход памяти из-за копирования при проверке на полиндром, если его убрать, то потребление памяти заметно снизиться (при больших объемах ввода), но это уже оставлю Вам.

PS также не стоит использовать `using namespace std;` - это плохая практика.